# Objective-C: technical reasons to avoid _ as a local variable name?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, naming-conventions, variable-names

Consider this in the (possibly nested) scope of a method (function, block, etc.):

```
int _ = 42;
```

Are there any *technical* reasons to avoid a local variable named `_`?

Some guidance, for the *purpose of this question*:

- I know `_` generally prefixes Objective-C instance variables. 
  Leave that aside. Commentary on other clashes with *convention* welcomed.
- I like pretty code too, but statements of taste or pure opinion (e.g. "It's {confusing, unreadable, unmaintainable}") are *strongly* discouraged *here*†.
- I'm primarily interested in answering this for Objective-C, but answers
  related to C or C++ are also encouraged.

† Buy me a pint, and you can tell me all about it. :)

Comment: The only downside I see, is it's not a descriptive name for a variable, expect for that, it's a valid C variable name: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Variables#Naming_Variables

Comment: In fact it is a very good practice if you want to be a one-liner and obfuscated code (both at the same time).

Comment: I'm looking for technical facts. While what you guys say may be good practice, a lot of programming is craft, and I would still consider them "statements of taste or pure opinion".

Comment: Question for whoever close-voted this as "primarily opinion-based": did you read the parts about "Are there any _technical_ reasons" and "statements of opinion discouraged"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C99 §7.1.3 says that all identifiers beginning with at least one underscore are reserved for use by the implementation, *as file-scope identifiers only*.<sup>1</sup> `_` is an identifier that begins with at least one underscore, so you're not supposed to define it in any way at file scope.<sup>2</sup>

However, as a *local* variable name, `_` is fair game for the application programmer.  Only identifiers beginning with either *two* underscores, or an underscore and then an uppercase letter, are reserved unconditionally.

These rules are honored more in the breach than the observance, as the footnotes demonstrate.

<sup>1</sup> Yes, that means the very common practice of starting "internal use only" function names with `_` followed by a lowercase letter is technically a conformance violation.

<sup>2</sup> [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) is a prominent third-party library that breaks this rule; the programmer is encouraged to `#define _(x) gettext(x)` as shorthand.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of information I was looking for. I'll very likely be green checking you in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question simply - no, there aren't any *technical* reasons to avoid it. Lots of other reasons though.

Comment: I think poor maintainability is a technical reason.

Comment: @HotLicks I edited the question to specifically exclude maintainability from scope.